# Swagger 2.0 Parser error duplicated mapping key

Tags: api, swagger

[image]

Parser error, duplicated mapping key, Jump to line 52
Issues while adding common parameter id

Comment: Can you please paste the complete yaml as string instead of an image? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: The error seems self-explanatory…

Comment: The indentation in line 45 is not correct. It seems this is also the case for line 44.

Answer (score 0):

Line 44 is over-indented. Replace

```
    /tasks/{id}:
    get:
```

with

```
  /tasks/{id}:
    get:
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a lot to fix.

There were multiple `parameters` defined in one operation.

The path `/tasks/{id}` was defined multiple times.
=> You have to use once and put each http-method inside this path.

I tried my best to create the YAML and I hope I fixed it correctly.
It's much easier to do such stuff, if the complete code is part of the question.

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: Sample API v2
  description: Sample Data API v2
  contact:
    name: John Smith
    email: john.smith@email.com
  version: v2
servers:
  - url: https://task-manager-pvs.herokuapp.com/ 
paths: 
  /tasks: 
    get: 
      tags: 
        - Tasks
      summary: Get All Tasks 
      operationId: GetAllTasks 
      parameters: [] 
      responses: 
        '200': 
          description: '' 
          headers: {} 
      deprecated: false 
      security: [] 

    post: 
      tags: 
        - Tasks 
      summary: Create Task 
      operationId: CreateTask 
      parameters: [] 
      requestBody: 
        description: '' 
        content: 
          application/json: 
            schema: 
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/CreateTaskRequest' 
            example: 
              name: test 
              required: true 
      responses: 
        '200': 
          description: '' 
          headers: {} 
      deprecated: false 
      security: [] 

  /tasks/{id}: 
    get: 
      tags:
      - Single Task 
      parameters: 
        - name: id
          in: path
          required: true
          schema: 
            type: string
      description: The Task ID 
      summary: Get Single Task 
      operationId: GetSingleTask 
      responses: 
        '200': 
          description: '' 
          headers: {} 
      deprecated: false 
      security: [] 
    patch: 
      tags: 
        - Single Task 
      summary: Update Task 
 
      parameters: 
          - in: path
            name: id 
            schema:
              type: string 
            required: true 
      description: The Task ID 
      operationId: UpdateTask 

      requestBody: 
        description: '' 
        content: 
          application/json: 
            schema: 
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/UpdateTaskRequest' 
            example: 
              name: st 
              required: true 
      responses: 
        '200':
          description: '' 
          headers: {} 
      deprecated: false 
      security: [] 

    delete: 
      parameters: 
      - in: path 
        name: id 
        schema: 
          type: string 
        required: true 
      description: The Task ID
      tags: 
        - Single Task 
      summary: Delete Task
      operationId: DeleteTask 
      responses: 
        '200': 
          description: '' 
          headers: {} 
      deprecated: false 
      security: [] 

components:
  schemas: 
    CreateTaskRequest: 
      title: CreateTaskRequest 
      required: 
        - name
      type: object 
      properties: 
        name: 
          type: string 
          example: 
            name: test       
            
    UpdateTaskRequest: 
      title: UpdateTaskRequest 
      required: 
        - name 
      type: object 
      properties: 
        name: 
          type: string 
          example: 
            name: st 
tags:
  - name: Tasks 
    description: ''
  - name: Single Task 
    description: ''
```